# Does JQuery.parseHTML() handle <source> element names correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use JQuery to parse a simple XML fragment with an element named `<source>` using either `$(xml)` or `$.parseHTML(xml)`. The resulting object is parsed incorrectly with an empty `<source />` tag, and the source tag contents as a text node sibling. For instance, with `var xml` set to this XML fragment:

```
<root>
    <name>Some name</name>
    <source>Some source</source>
</root>
```

calling `console.log($(xml)[0])` results in:

```
<root>
    <name>Some name</name>
    <source />
    "Some source"
</root>
```

Note the empty `</source>` tag and the text as a sibling.

However, it works fine when the element name is changed to `sourced`. Or if I use `$.parseXML(xml)`, the DOM contains the correct `<source>Some source</source>` content.

Here's a [JSBin as an example](http://jsbin.com/xuzaqol/4/edit?html,js,output).

Is this a JQuery bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source), 
`<source>` is an empty HTML element, like `<img>` and `<input>`. You can't use it to surround text, and there's no `</source>` tag (so this invalid tag is ignored). It's used to specify the location of resources for the `<picture>`, `<audio>`, or `<video>` element that contains it, as in this example:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="foo.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="foo.ogg" type="video/ogg"> 
  <source src="foo.mov" type="video/quicktime">
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

`$.parseHTML()` parses it as a browser would (in fact, it usually just uses the browser's own HTML parsing function).

Since your data is XML, not HTML, you should use `$.parseXML()` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - that makes perfect sense now. I'll switch over to `$.parseXML()` for our XML content.